# UWP - Multilingual : Change of language string at runtime

Tags: uwp, globalization, resx, multilingual-app-toolkit

When we have multiple languages in UWP (Xliff and Resx). at runtime windows decides which language to load or manually also we can change using   Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride.

I wish to know where are the resources loaded, in which class/object ?  I wish to know if after resx are loaded can i change the contents of a specific resource id in memory/object itself. So that on screen it displays the modified content of specific resource id.

I am asking because resx files are also compiled and after which there is no way to change/update resx file at runtime. So i am looking for alternative ways.

Regards

Comment: I have a little bit confused about your question, do you mean you want to change the value of some string inside the resources file or do you just want to let the control use another string from the resources file?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I've to say that UWP doesn't have APIs that could change the values inside the resources files. You need to modify these values manually and package your app with a new version. Then you could update your app on other devices. I'd suggest you pre-define more strings in your resources files for different scenarios. So you could switch to different values using **ResourceLoader Class** if you really need to do that.

**Old reply:**
If you just want to use another value to replace the old value that you've already assigned to a control, for example, there is a `TextBlock` object which already uses the `Hello` string (**Hello** is the name in the resource file, not the value) from the resource file as text.  And now you want to use another resource string `FareWell` to replace the `Hello` string. If this is what you want, you could use the [ResourceLoader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader?view=winrt-22000) to achieve this.

What you need to do in the code-behind looks like:

```
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
//the myXAMLTextBlockElement text uses x:uid= Hello in the xaml
this.myXAMLTextBlockElement.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("Farewell");
```

Comment: Well, Sorry for the confusion..  let me re-explain.   a textblock will have x:uid="tbMsg.Text"  so on startup system loads the right language resource (resx/resw) and it will auto pickup the assigned string.  What I want to do is to find where all resx resources are loaded in memory and replace content there, so that if x:uid="tbMsg.Text" is used at multiple places, I do not need to write too many lines of code.  Just at startup change the original resx content in memory as soon as its loaded and then onwards rest will be taken care automatically.

Comment: @Neha That's impossible to replace the value in the resources files. If you don't want to use that content, why don't you directly modify the resources files before running the app?

Comment: I had same thoughts, but Sr. are looking for options. in nut sell, Large applications, multiple clients, you see, deploying minor but frequent fixes to resx, has lots of efforts and time.  So exploring options or workarounds to get some better ideas to manage things.

Comment: @Neha I've updated my answer. In short, there is no way to modify the resource files without updating your package.

Comment: Is there any inbuild available resources classes to read/write resx files from disk (either localFolder or TemporaryFolder)  in UWP

Comment: You could check this [Create, write, and read a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files). Again, it is not recommended to modify the resx files at runtime. It may cause runtime exceptions.